# How do you toggle/expand specific mapped button IN a component using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

Every time I expand a specific card, all character cards expand, when I only want the specific one to. I am using the star wars api, using react-hooks and material-ui.

From what I know and read, I am able to pass the index through the handleClick() event but in the handleClick function itself is where I get lost. I try to attach the index to the expanded state but I will get an error saying I can't attach the number to a boolean. I also understand that separating the component and mapping could be the solution and that makes sense but I haven't been able to do it. It's been a couple days so now im reaching out for help if possible. Thanks.

The app.js File

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/");
        setLoading(false);
        // console.log(result.data.results);
        setData(result.data.results);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("there was an error");
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CssBaseline />
      <Typography variant="h1">React Wars</Typography>
      <Icon>star</Icon>
      <MediaCard data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The card.js file

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    card: {
      width: 200,
      marginBottom: 16
    },
    media: {
      height: 0,
      paddingTop: "56.25%" // 16:9
    },
    expand: {
      transform: "rotate(0deg)",
      marginLeft: "auto",
      transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest
      })
    },
    expandOpen: {
      transform: "rotate(180deg)"
    },
    avatar: {
      backgroundColor: red[500],
      margin: 0
    },
    card_container: {
      display: "flex",
      maxWidth: 1064,
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      margin: "auto",
      justifyContent: "space-between"
    }
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  function handleExpandClick(index) {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  }

  const a = props.data.map((data, index) => {
    return (
      <Card className={classes.card} key={index}>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            marginTop: 16
          }}
        >
          <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
            {data.name.charAt(0)}
          </Avatar>
          {
            <Typography variant="h5" key={index} style={{ margin: "8px auto" }}>
              {data.name}
            </Typography>
          }
        </div>

        <IconButton
          className={clsx(classes.expand, {
            [classes.expandOpen]: expanded
          })}
          onClick={() => handleExpandClick(index)}
          aria-expanded={expanded}
          aria-label="show more"
        >
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
        </IconButton>

        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography paragraph>{data.gender}</Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>{data.eye_color}</Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>{data.height}</Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Collapse>
      </Card>
    );
  });

  return <div className={classes.card_container}>{a}</div>;
};

export default MediaCard;
```

UPDATE:

I separated the components and am able to show only the data for each character but still not able to isolate the expand function to the specific card. I created a codesandbox link to see my code if that helps. Thanks.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-frog-p0k8w?fontsize=14

Comment: you only have one `expanded` state variable. If you want to be able to expand items individually you will need to have a separate `expanded` value for each item

Comment: @MoIsmat Thanks for your help. I am still having difficulty understanding how to map a separate expanded state using hooks. The most progress I have got so far is only displaying data of the specific character. I created a codesandbox to show my code. Maybe this will help

https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-frog-p0k8w?fontsize=14

Comment: I think you're trying to learn too many things at once. I advise you to first try doing this without using Material-ui. Just use a div with a button to expand the content. Make it a reusable component, then use it with all your items. After you get React figured out, you can then move to learning libraries like material-ui

Comment: @MoIsmat I figured it out. The issue was styling as my code was right (not sure if structurally right as Im still learning but functional lol). The row the card was on increased the height of all cards in that row only so I controlled the height of each  card. A quick fix for me was making the card height 100% and it seemed to work. I did do one without material-ui's expand still which did help me see the issue so thanks for the advice. If you see anything else in my code that maybe Im doing wrong or couldve done better please let me know. Ill attach both code samples in another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I set up a codesandbox to see my code. Progress I have made so far is only displaying data of the specific character but still having difficulties understanding how to create the mapped data's own state. Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-frog-p0k8w?fontsize=14

UPDATE: I FIGURED IT OUT
The issue was styling as my code was right (not sure if structurally right as Im still learning but functional lol). The row the card was on increased the height of all cards in that row only so I controlled the height of each  card. A quick fix for me was making the card height 100% and it seemed to work. I did do one without material-ui's expand still which did help me see the issue so thanks for the advice.

If you see anything else in my code that maybe Im doing wrong or couldve done better please let me know as I am always trying to improve. Ill attach both code samples below.

WITH MATERIAL-UI EXPAND
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-frog-p0k8w?fontsize=14

WITHOUT Material-UI Expand
https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-burnell-ju158?fontsize=14